# Как задать footer в React js Bootsrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap, reactjs

Хочу сделать компонент реакта, который служил бы footer'ом для веб страницы. В документации по react-bootstrap нашел упоминание о футере только в связке с модальным окном(у этого компонента есть и header и footer). Также нашел вот [вот такую штуку](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/pull/590/files), но прикрутить ее не получилось. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить данный вопрос, может есть какой-то туториал,на базе которого это можно реализовать?
код моего компонента(пункты списков ul удалил для лучшего восприятия кода):

```
const SearchBar = React.createClass({
    _onChange: function (e) {
        this.props.onChange(e);
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <FormGroup>
                <InputGroup>
                    <FormControl type="text"
                                 placeholder="Search..."
                                 name={name}
                                 onChange={this._onChange}

                    />
                    <FormControl.Feedback />
                    <InputGroup.Button>
                        <Button bsStyle="danger"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> </span></Button>
                    </InputGroup.Button>
                </InputGroup>                  
            </FormGroup>
        );
    }
});

const IconBar = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-2">
                    <a href="" aria-hidden="true">
                        <Image src="/img/icons/facebook.png" responsive/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-2">
                    <a href="" aria-hidden="true">
                        <Image src="/img/icons/googleplus.png" responsive/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-2">
                    <a href="" aria-hidden="true">
                        <Image src="/img/icons/twitter.png" responsive/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-2">
                    <a href="" aria-hidden="true">
                        <Image src="/img/icons/linkedin.png" responsive/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-2">
                    <a href="" aria-hidden="true">
                        <Image src="/img/icons/yahoo.png" responsive/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var Footer = React.createClass({

    render: function () {

        var footerStyle = {
            color: 'white',
            backgroundColor:'#4b4a45'
                };

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid" style={footerStyle}>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-5">
                            <ul>                                                        
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-5">
                            <ul>               
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <IconBar/>
                        <SearchBar/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <div className="row">

                        <div className="col-md-5">
                            <ul>                    
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-4">
                            <ul>                                
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default Footer;
```

Comment: Чего хотите то? Что вам мешает просто взять свой футер, и вернуть в методе рендер вашу разметку с навешанными бутстраповскими классами? Или вам от него какая-то интерактивность нужна?

Comment: если я подброшу свой класс со своей разметкой, не будет потом под ни образовываться пустота в каких-то случаях?просто из html знаю,что footer это низ страницы, под ним ничего не будет. а как дело обстоит с реактовскими компонентами не знаю, потому и решил спросить. может есть какой-то элемент с жесткой привязкой к низу, который в случае чего не уползет...

Comment: Ох. Я все понял, для вас бутстрап и реакт - это магия. Так вот, это блин не магия, это обычный js и css. Футер - это просто класс с position:absolute и bottom:0. Реакт не тронет ничего, если вы ручками virtual dom не пофиксите, а создадите как нормальный jsx элемент. В созднии футера скрипты бутстрапа не замешаны, только стили. Подключаете бутстраповский цсс и вешаете стиль футера на ваш элемент черзе className.

Comment: то есть нужно просто дописать в стиле так: var footerStyle = {
            color: 'white',
            backgroundColor:'#4b4a45',
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 0
                };?

Comment: Скорее что-то в духе render: function(){return <div className="footer"></div>}. В бутстрапе уже есть класс делающий футер, вам только надо грамотно создать черзе реакт элемент с висящим на нем классом. Вешать инлайн стили через js - моветон. Я крайне рекомендую вам уделить время на то чтобы чуть-чуть понять технологии которыми вы пользуетесь.

Comment: получилось, но перестал работать  backgroundColor:'#4b4a45' в  footerStyle. цвет шрифта через color: можно менять, а вот фоновый цвет элемента-нет